# SP 2013: how can i make my script editor web part to overlap with other web parts?

Tags: html, css, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, overlap

I have recently started on Sharepoint 2013 online, so a pretty noobie here.

As mentioned in the title, would like to get some answers or ideas if it is possible to make my script editor web part (contents) to be able to overlap with the other web parts? 
Thank you.

Here's  a picture of this issue:
[~~~~~~](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsCq7.png)

Comment: can you please elaborate more exactly what are you trying to achieve.....

Comment: Hi Rohit Waghela,

I made a Mega Menu with the use of Script Editor web part and a custom data list use of Content Editor web part, below the mega menu. 

However, when i am on the view mode, my mega menu dropdown appears not to be "overlap" the custom data list. 

So would like to get some suggestions/answers about this issue. Thank you. -XxmfenxX

Comment: SOLVED: i have solved my issue. I forgot about the z-index css attribute onto my dropdown menu. 

z-index: 999!important;

Comment: Could you please post the solution as an answer; so it will be easier for others to know "How" you did it!